# Programatically checking all checkbox doesn't work properly when any of the target checkboxes checked / unchecked manually

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Programatically checking all checkbox doesn't work properly when any of the target checkboxes checked / unchecked manually
I have two methods, where one will check all the checkboxes and other will un check all the checkbox values

I named them selectAll and unSelectall. when selectAll  is triggered, it will check all the checkbox but when unSelectall is triggered it unchecks all the checkbox but what the problem is when you check / uncheck the any of the target checkboxes and then you click the checkall or uncheck all, the manually checked/ unchecked checkboxes don't work. here is the working code on [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s8juvkmw/)

```
function selectAll() {
    const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.myCheck');
    let i = 0;
    while(i < checkboxes.length) {
      checkboxes[i].setAttribute("checked", "checked");
      i++;
    }
  }
  function unSelectAll() {  
    const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.myCheck');
    let i = 0;
    while(i < checkboxes.length) {
      checkboxes[i].removeAttribute("checked", "");
      i++;
    }
  }
```

Comment: As suggested by @[gurvinder372](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48335496/3783478), you should use `.checked`. But you do not need 2 functions. You can create a single function that would take `true` for select and `false` for unselect and process accordingly. [Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s8juvkmw/5/). Also, `id` of an element should be unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `setAttribute` and `removeAttribute`, use the direct `checked` property

```
  function selectAll() {
    const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.myCheck');
    let i = 0;
    while (i < checkboxes.length) {
      checkboxes[i].checked = true;
      i++;
    }
  }

  function unSelectAll() {
    const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.myCheck');
    let i = 0;
    while (i < checkboxes.length) {
      checkboxes[i].checked = false;
      i++;
    }
  }
```

**Demo**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <body>

    All:
    <input onclick="selectAll();" type="checkbox" id="all"> uncheckAll:
    <input onclick="unSelectAll();" type="checkbox" id="all">
    <br/> ckbx1:
    <input type="checkbox" class="myCheck"> ckbx2:
    <input type="checkbox" class="myCheck"> ckbx3:
    <input type="checkbox" class="myCheck"> ckbx4:
    <input type="checkbox" class="myCheck">

    <p>checl all and uncheck all</p>

    <script>
      function selectAll() {
        const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.myCheck');
        let i = 0;
        while (i < checkboxes.length) {
          checkboxes[i].checked = true;
          i++;
        }
      }

      function unSelectAll() {
        const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.myCheck');
        let i = 0;
        while (i < checkboxes.length) {
          checkboxes[i].checked = false;
          i++;
        }
      }

    </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Maybe you need to add a check only if `all` and `uncheckAll` are checked, you have to proceed. Consider the case: 1. Select check all. 2. Select unchckall. (Now nothing will be checked except checkall and uncheckall boxes). 3. Now uncheck the checkall box. (all checkboxes will be checked. Since onclick is fired no matter the state of the selected box, it performs the operation)

Comment: @VigneshRaja That is part of UX and is out of scope of question. I agree to the point but the question is only about *select/unselect* all. Lets not over engineer it.

Comment: .checked = true; produces a typescript error "property checked doesnt exist on type element"

Comment: @karty typescript? Typescript wasn't part of your original question. Can you share a fiddle that reproduce the error?

Comment: I understand this is a type error. Thanks for spending your valuable time to answer my question. accepting your answer. upvoting my question will be appreciated.